# Talking to moving NPCs in Minecraft 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

### Context:

In order to trigger a chat message "from" NPCs - say villagers - when approaching them, I am using an always-active repeat-command block (A), a redstone-signal-sensitive impulse-command block (B) and a redstone comparator between them, pointing from A to B.

[image]

Since I want to let the NPCs run free, I can't use absolute coordinates, so what I'm currently doing is:

```
A: execute at @e[name=Gary] if entity @p[distance=..2]
B: execute at @e[name=Gary] run tellraw @a[distance=..2] "Hey!"
```

This results in the chat message "Hey!" to appear once for every player with distance 2 blocks or less to an entity named Gary as soon as a player is detected in that space.

---

### Question:

Since it is odd that Gary talks to people in front of him as well as to people behind him, is it possible to alter the commands in a way that the center of the area in which players are detected (and in which players have to be to get the message) is not at exactly Gary's position, but 1 block in front of him?

[image]

---

### Deliberations:

- If Gary always stood in the same spot, it would be easy by using absolute coordinates like this:

  ```
  A: execute if entity @p[x=x_,y=y_,z=z_,distance=..2]
  B: tellraw @a[x=x_,y=y_,z=z_,distance=..2] "Hey!"
  ```

  x_, y_ and z_ being the desired coordinates 1 block in front of Gary.
- Since version 1.13 it is possible to use caret notation for coordinates in some commands making them relative coordinates considering the command's executor's viewing direction, but it seems that target selector arguments only support absolute coordinates in Java edition.

Comment: See if this works: /execute at @e[type=villager] as @s positioned ^ ^ ^2 run tellraw @a[distance=..2] {"text":"Hey!"}

Comment: @SpiceWeasel This seems to work if I paste it into the chat by myself standing in front of a villager (regardless of my viewing direction which is good), but running in a command block it does nothing.
Isn't "at" the same as "positioned" with the difference that "at" uses all three, the position, the rotation and the dimension of the subject and "positioned" only uses the position? So "execute at @e[type=villager]" would be the same as "execute positioned as @e[type=villager] rotated as @e[type=villager] in minecraft:overworld" if the villager resides in the overworld?

Comment: I haven't read the entire question yet, but I'm wondering about your setup. When do you expect the comparator to activate? How I understand it, it would never do it.

Comment: I can't access Minecraft currently, so my answer will have to wait some hours, but you can definitely use the caret notation with `execute positioned`, then you don't even need `xyz` in the selector anymore. Also, your two commands don't need to be two. Just make one, it does the same. Not sure what your comparator is supposed to do, but if you want to tell the player only once, just give him a tag and make the speaking command only target players without the tag.

Comment: @Fabian: Why this setup? You guessed it: I want the message to only show up once instead of every tick the player is standing in the right area. (A) constantly checks if a player is standing in the area and if so, the comparator activates and stays activated as long as the player's position matches the condition. As a result, (B) gets only activated once, that is when the player enters the area and (A)'s output is true for the first time. Both of my example command pairs work perfectly.

Comment: @Fabian: Yes you are right, the caret notation is possible with `positioned`. However, I don't know how to make use of that since primarily I want the center at the villager's position, but 1 block in front of him. So wouldn't I need `at @e[...]` primarily? But what next? `at` and `positioned` don't seem to be combinable because they both read the position of the subject and one would overwrite the other in one command?

Comment: @Fabian: And yes, I think I need at least two command blocks. Even if I'd work with tags, the repeating command block would print the message every tick sensing the player with the right tag, wouldn't it? I'd need a second chained and conditional command block, which resets the tag so the player is a match only at the first detection. Btw: I am using a scorebord objective "storyState", which increments every time the player progresses in the story. This state is checked inside B besides the player's dist so a message is only displayed to people in the right state. I hope I am understandable.

Comment: @Maevur 1. I didn't know that repeating auto command blocks activate comparators without being powered by redstone themselves, interesting. 2. The player could exit and enter again, right? A tag is safer. Also, boo, redstone components in command block contraptions! :P 3. Yes, with tags you would need two command blocks. Not for resets though, since you never want it to reset, it should only ever happen once. I'll give more details in my answer at about 17 o'clock UTC. And yes, your state scoreboard is a good idea as well, very well fit for progressing through phases. I'll include that, too.

Comment: @Fabian Allright, I'm looking forward to your solution! (I heard about the ugliness of combining command blocks with redstone, but it worked and I considered that slim and clever in that case because of no tedious tag-tinkering and stuff... :-D) Btw, additionally, I want the villagers to say different things in different game states. I actually call a function in block B which contains different messages for different states and sometimes a state increment if a player with the right state speaks to the right villager. Would be cool if you considered that, too!

Comment: @Maevur I'm not sure if you and Fabian figured this out yet or not but I'm pretty sure at only uses the location of the entity for execution, and positioned uses the coordinates starting from the entity. So I'm pretty sure positioned would execute two blocks in front of the entity (and I know this works for me in my functions). Why it isn't working for you, I don't know. Maybe I don't know the situation enough, but it looks like Fabian's doing a good job helping you so I'll just let you two figure it out :)

Comment: @SpiceWeasel @Fabian First off: I got Mr. Weasel's command to work by interchanging the words `at` and `as`: `/execute as @e[type=villager] at @s positioned ^ ^ ^2 run tellraw @a[distance=..2] {"text":"Hey!"}` I don't know why the two versions are not identical... I would've thought they are. I technically have now what I need to go on if I split this command into two and put them into my command block setup. But I am really curious about your redstone-less, tag-based suggestion, Fabian, which is why I'm encouraging you to write it down anyway (even if "just" for the community).

Comment: @Maevur This site only tags the first mentioned user (and the post creator), so I got no notification for your comment.

Comment: @Fabian Ups, and again I learned something! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the caret notation (`^`) in `execute positioned`, which removes the need for the `x`, `y` and `z` target selectors entirely (except in some really niche cases). The command you need is this one:

```
execute at @e[type=villager] positioned ^ ^ ^2 run tellraw @a[distance=..2] "Hey!"
```

---

As a bonus, you can get rid of the comparator (and also prevent that players why enter the radius multiple times get the message multiple times) by putting this command after the first:

```
execute at @e[type=villager] positioned ^ ^ ^2 run tag @a[distance=..2] add heardVillagerTalk
```

and modifying the first command to:

```
execute at @e[type=villager] positioned ^ ^ ^2 run tellraw @a[distance=..2,tag=!heardVillagerTalk] "Hey!"
```

This will prevent the issue the comparator had that players could walk in and out of the area and get the message every time.

---

If you're using a state scoreboard in your map, you can of course do the same with that. Let's say that state 0 is before having "heard" the "villager" "talk" and state 1 is afterwards. Make this command the second command in the row:

```
execute at @e[type=villager] positioned ^ ^ ^2 if entity @a[distance=..2] run scoreboard players set $game state 1
```

And make both only activate in state 0. This assumes that your state scoreboard is called "state" and the holder "$game".

Comment: Additional hint: Never use `scoreboard players add` for the game state, otherwise there might be bugs that increase it multiple times, skipping important states or even parts of the map. Credits warp!

Comment: Ah, so SpiceWeasel's code can either be fixed by swapping `at` with `as` or by leaving out `as` completely. Good to know! Also thanks for the instructions for tags and the game state (and the additional hint).